How to identify growing usage on a hosted server?
I run a hosted server with 250GB of storage space. The storage used on this server fluctuates by as much as 15% throughout the day. Lately, this usage has exceeded 80% most of the day, and for the past few days I have noticed it doesn't go below 80%.
Best practices say that utilization should be kept below 80%, and in fact I get alerts from the provider ("an issue you need to fix") under this circumstance.
A few days ago, I did some trimming by removing big backup files that were grandfathers of other backups, and got to a comfortable 71%, but by end of day it was back around 85%.  Now the range for the course of a day seems to be about 82-90%.
I have analyzed output of du -ms|sort -rn|head for top-level directories, and drilled down the paths of the larger ones similarly, but nothing really stands out: the larger stuff tends to be files that are static or that rarely change.
What tools are available to help me identify the source of this fluctuation so that I can take steps to resolve the situation?  If I must upgrade, then c'est la vie but I think there's something going on beyond simple disk utilization.
Daily at 2:00AM to 3:00AM, there are processes that clean up MySQL logs and the like (and not coincidentally, system storage usage is at a low about 3:00AM daily).
I also was concerned, (since I have found no other answer) that space was being held by unlinked-but-open files.  But reboot had a near zero impact on utilization, so I don't think the answer is there.

Update: I'm told the following is irrelevant.  Leaving it in for nostalgia. I'll concede the point.
There is a super huge file /proc/kcore that seems to be part of the cost of running Linux. Didn't notice that before, but seems it's pretty standard.

Way back when I tracked disk usage on a spreadsheet, and then used various features of Excel to give me an accurate prediction line based on the growth in order to tell when we'd need to add more storage by. But, if you're just looking to identify WHAT is eating the space, that's manual. You look at the files that are growing, and then you look at what is growing them, and then you look at why that process is growing those files, and up the chain until you find the source.

"There is a super huge file /proc/kcore …" – Irrelevant, as /proc is a virtual filesystem, it does not consume storage space; so it's not even "part of the cost of running Linux".

Check out ncdu. It’s somewhat like du, but interactive. Use ncdu -x /. (du also has -x and you absolutely should use it—investigate one filesystem at a time.)

What version of MySQL are you using? This all sounds like growth in the /var/lib/mysql directory. This suggestion is for MySQL 8.x.
Do you have a MySQL config? Such as in /etc/my.cnf? If you are using MySQL 8.x I would recommend you set sync_binlog = 1 in that config. Something like this:
[mysqld]
sync_binlog = 1

And then restart MySQL. If you don’t know what sync_binlog (or the binlog) is don’t worry about it. This setting will prevent the binlog value from constantly creating files and filling up space.
In my experience, you will never miss these binlog files; they mainly transaction files that are only useful if you know how to use them. And most average users don’t know how to use them.

Thanks, @giacomo1968.  It is version 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1  I used to be a DBA working with Oracle and DB2.  But that was long ago.  I appreciate your adivce.  Since this system currently has no use for binlog, I have added the parameter and restarted.  Will accept once I see the resolution.

After some time, it is clear that this was my problem, as usage quickly came back down to normal levels, and maintained a more level growth line over time..  I've accepted this answer because it led me to my solution (and because I said I would). I would have liked to have seen a way to determine definitively that this (or something else) was the problem, but the insight by @giacomo1968 solved the real issue for me in this case.  Thanks, Man!
